# How to update a macOS bundle without breaking notarization?

Tags: swift, macos, notarize

I have an application which can be extended with additional functions through small installer bundles. During the installation additional files are placed within the app bundle. How can I ensure that notarization is still valid afterwards? All possibilities in this workflow break the signature. Am I missing something?

Problem is that I can't include this loading of additional functions within the application. It must be provided via an external installer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify a bundle after it's notarized. (If you could, what would be the point of notarizing?) It sounds like you have plug-ins, which is supported. You just need to notarize the plug-ins separately. Generally they should be installed in a support directory, not in your app bundle.